# Using pd.to_datetime to convert int with format HHMMSS

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the following code in Python to transform a dataframe column of ints corresponding to hour, minute and seconds(E.g. 230100) to a time format.

```
data_name['Time'] = data_name['Time'].apply(lambda y: pd.to_datetime(str(y),format='%H%M%S'))
```

I am having the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '230100' does not match format '%H%M%S' (match)
```

The previous type of code worked perfectly to convert an int with the info YYYYMMDD.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me working nice in pandas 0.25.0, what is your pandas version? Also `apply` is not necessary here:

```
data_name = pd.DataFrame({'Time':[230100,230100]})

data_name['Time'] = (pd.to_datetime(data_name['Time'].astype(str), 
                                    errors='coerce',
                                    format='%H%M%S').dt.time)
print (data_name)
       Time
0  23:01:00
1  23:01:00
```

Comment: @BrunoAlb - If run my sample data working nice for you?

Comment: My pandas version is 0.25.3 but it does not work yet. Still have the same error

Comment: Also a new error appeared in addition to the one explained above:
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'int'>

Comment: @BrunoAlb - one idea - can you check with casting to strings `data_name['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data_name['Time'].astype(str), format='%H%M%S').dt.time` ?

Comment: Didn't work, the error changed to:
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>
I tried to include: errors='coerce' and now it is working...weird

Comment: @BrunoAlb - I think reason is there are some not matched values `HHMMSS`, it should be reason for failed parsing.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this can help:

```
pd.to_datetime(data_name['Time'],format='%H%M%S').dt.time
```